# Select from table max temperature on specific date

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table with the following data

```
Temperature    DateTimeValue         WarnCrit
29.1        2020-06-22 10:08:30         0
29.2        2020-06-22 09:38:28         0
29.2        2020-06-22 09:08:26         0
28.9        2020-06-22 08:38:26         0
28.7        2020-06-22 08:08:24         0
28.7        2020-06-22 07:38:22         0
29.2        2020-06-22 07:08:21         0
29.8        2020-06-22 06:38:20         0
29.9        2020-06-22 06:08:18         0
```

i like to make a select to find the maximum,minimum,average temperature on specific date so i use the following:

```
SELECT max(Temperature) as maxtemp
     , min(Temperature) as mintemp
     , avg(Temperature) as avtemp 
  FROM TempHistory 
 WHERE date(DateTimeValue)='2020-06-22'
```

This work correct, but i like also to have the specific time that this temperature occured. so i change it to :

```
SELECT * 
  from TempHistory 
 where DateTimeValue = '2020-06-22' 
   and Temperature = (select max(Temperature) from TempHistory)
```

and this return nothing.

Comment: The subquery needs the date too.

Comment: I try it and still return nothing and thank you for the formating!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions, particularly `first_value()`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT max(Temperature) OVER () as maxtemp,
       min(Temperature) OVER () as mintemp,
       avg(Temperature) OVER () as avtemp,
       FIRST_VALUE(DateTimeValue) OVER (ORDER BY Temperature ASC) as dt_at_min,
       FIRST_VALUE(DateTimeValue) OVER (ORDER BY Temperature DESC) as dt_at_max
FROM TempHistory 
WHERE DateTimeValue >= '2020-06-22' AND
      DateTimeValue < '2020-06-23';
```

Unfortunately, MySQL (and SQL in general) doesn't have a "first" or "last" aggregation function.  However, this is quite similar.

Also note the change to the `WHERE`.  This allows the query to make use of an index on `DateTimeValue` -- if one is available.

Comment: woow!!! i didn't t expect something like that! Thank you alot, i will try it at once, I will read about distinct and over, but is it possible to try and explain me a little? Thank you again!!

Comment: Also, can i use the following to get this values for the month and the year?  `WHERE DateTimeValue >= '2020-06' AND    
      DateTimeValue < '2020-07';`

Comment: I would suggest using full dates:  `'2020-06-01'` and `'202-07-01'` for the constants.  I think MySQL supports partial dates, but there is no need for them.

Comment: I use your solution, but i go to the following error.  Error
"Static analysis:

42 errors were found during analysis.

An alias was previously found. (near "maxtemp" at position 44)
An alias was expected. (near " " at position 43)
Unexpected token. (near "maxtemp" at position 44)
Unexpected token. (near "," at position 51)
Unrecognized keyword. (near "min" at position 61)
Unexpected token. (near "(" at position 64)
Unexpected token. (near "Temperature" at position 65)"

Comment: @GKal . . . I don't know what tool you are using for that but there are definitely not 42 errors in the code by any measure.  I might guess that the tool doesn't recognize window functions.

Comment: its from phpmyadmin. I have rent a server because i cant make mine run 24/7 because its change the ip(not static) I try to find a cheap server to use for 1 month but when i run the select i get to data back. So i run the phpmyadmin on the server side and i see the errors. Following the sql version that they have install.
Server version: 5.6.41-84.1 - Percona Server (GPL), Release 84.1, Revision b308619
Protocol version: 10
If you need any other info or if you can help me setup my server(i try serveo it doesnt work) Please i will be full of ears!THANK YOU! Really! from my hart for your time!

Comment: the above answer is a follow up. Do you have any idea about that?

Answer (score 1):

If there are no ties (or you don't care about them), you could write this as:

```
select t.* 
from TempHistory t
where t.DateTimeValue = (
    select t1.DateTimeValue
    from TempHistory t1
    where t1.DateTimeValue >= '2020-06-22' and t1.DateTimeValue < '2020-06-23'
    order by Temperature desc
    limit 1
)
```

Rationale:

- your dates have time portion, so you need to an inequality filter
- it is simpler to use a subquery that returns the date with the highest temperature rather than the temperature itself (hence, you don't need to filter on the date in the outer query)

If you want the row with the lowest temperature of the day, you can just remove `desc`from the `order by` clause.

Comment: I try this and i got back this error MySQL said: Documentation

#1051 - Unknown table 'database.t'
Also i like to ask, why you din't use the = on the where?
where date(t1.DateTimeValue) = '2020-06-21'?

Comment: @GKal: yes `date(t1.DateTimeValue) = '2020-06-21'` is possible, but it is more efficient to filter with half open intervals than to use date functions.

Comment: @GKal Because functions cannot use indexes

Comment: @GMB May I ask what is the difference between your answer and the following?
select * from TempHistory t1 where t1.DateTimeValue >= '2020-06-22' and t1.DateTimeValue < '2020-06-23' order by Temperature desc limit 1